# How to change the default Java (JDK) version on macOS?

Tags: macos, jvm, java-home

I try to change the default Java (JDK) version on macOS? It seems, that I use right commands, but it does not work. And I even do know why

1. find my jvm list:
   `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`
2. set JAVA_HOME value

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 17.0.2`
```

3. check result: `java --version`

But result shows 11.0.2 version. Why? What is wrong?

[image]

Comment: I tried restarting the terminal and computer, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I copied `openjdk-17.0.2` from `/Users/myusername/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` to `/Users/myusername/.sdkman/candidates/java/`.

After it I have:
[image]